# I have an issue with animating the height of my nav with jquery - it makes me click the button twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a nav to which the height is set to 0px. When i click on an element (here, #menu_button) the nav's height is supposed to change to a given height (here, 143px). This toggles it. My problem is that I'm made to click the button twice the first time before it works properly. Please help. Btw I'm new here.

Here's the code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="#port"><li><p>Portfolio</p></li></a>
        <a href="#about"><li><p>About Me</p></li></a>
        <a href="#contact"><li><p>Contact Me</p></li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="container_menu_button">
    <div id="menu_button">
        <div id="menu_pic"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(css of the nav)

```
nav {
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

(jquery)

```
<script>    
$("#menu_button").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
        $("nav").animate({height:"143px"}, 200);          
        $(this).removeClass("isDown");
    } else {
        $("nav").animate({height:"0px"}, 200);   
        $(this).addClass("isDown");
    }
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Some of your post isn't properly formatted.  If you could fix the following we could help you better: First, your jQuery code isn't in a code block and so it is a bit hard to read.  Second, your HTML is coming across as actual HTML and not code, so be sure that is in a code block too.  Thanks.

Comment: Check my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/Ywjce/ I didn't see anything wrong with your code.  I didn't have to click twice.

Comment: Your markup is invalid. `a` should be inside `li`, not the other way around.

Comment: @shaun - i had obtained the jquery code from another link on this site which seemed to work for that guy. i just copy-pasted it since im a noob at this. And i don't understand how it works in your link but not on my site. Weird. Thanks though.

Comment: @putvande - i want the entire li to be a link, hece the "a" before the li.

Comment: Yes, but it is not valid. You can just place the `a` inside the `li` and with CSS make the whole `li` clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click it twice because your menu_button div does not have an 'isDown' class to begin with. The first time you click it, it animates it to 0px (which it already is) and adds the class. Then, the second time you click it works as expected.

Do this:

```
<div id="menu_button" class="isDown">
```

Comment: I added the class name exactly as you said and it works like a charm. THANKS.